# Can a container with CAP_NET_ADMIN access the host namespace

Tags: docker, container

I have a docker container that I run by adding the extra privilege of `CAP_NET_ADMIN` in addition to the default ones. If I don’t share the host net namespace with the container, the host namespace is not visible from inside the container which makes sense. Is there any way for a container with the `cap_net_admin` privilege to access the host net namespace that I should be worried about?

I run the container using the following command.

```
docker run -it —-cap-add=CAP_NET_ADMIN <image name> /bin/bash
```